# How can I get the name of file when using DKImagepickerController in Swift 5

Tags: cocoapods, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5

I have successfully imported this library and now when I am trying to fetch the same of the File it gives error in Swift 5 earlier it was working..

I am writing below code for the same.

```
    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

    if mode == "Camera"{
        pickerController.sourceType = .camera
    }else if mode == "" {
        pickerController.sourceType = .photo
    }

    //pickerController.fetchLimit = 1
    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        for asset in assets {
            asset.fetchOriginalImage(completeBlock: { (image, info) in
                if let info = info, let fileURL = info["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL {
                    asset.fileName = fileURL.lastPathComponent ?? "Image"
                    print(asset.fileName)
                    let imageName = (((info["PHImageFileURLKey"]! as AnyObject).lastPathComponent!) as NSString)
                }else{
                    print("filename not found")
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

Can you please let me know Where I am going wrong
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 var imageName = ""
            if let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
                let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
                imageName = assetResources.first!.originalFilename
            } else {
                imageName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
            }
```